# How to convert a 2 column pandas dataframe to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has 2 columns: The first column is the minutes, and the second column is the seconds. It looks like this:

```
     min   s
0      0   0
1      0   1
2      0   2
3      0   3
4      0   4
5      0   5
6      0   6
7      0   7
8      0   8
9      0   9
10     0  10
11     0  11
12     0  12
```

How would I convert this to datetime in the format %M:%S?

Comment: What happens if you concat the two column values. `.str.cat()` and format the result as time

Answer (score 0):

I believe because you just have time only columns, you should avoid using datetime and use timedelta instead.

I would try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"minute":[0,1,2,3,4,5],"second":[30,40,50,60,10,20]})
df['time'] = df.agg('{0[minute]}:{0[second]}'.format, axis=1)
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['time'])
```

print(df) OUTPUTS, you could delete the minute and second columns afterwards if they're unecessary

```
   minute  second     time
0       0      30 00:00:30
1       1      40 00:01:40
2       2      50 00:02:50
3       3      60 00:04:00
4       4      10 00:04:10
5       5      20 00:05:20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []
for MinSec in list(zip(df['min'],df['s'])):
    l.append(':'.join(map(str,MinSec)))

pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(l), format='%M:%S')
```

Just `zip` min and s columns, join them using a `:` as separator and convert the series with `to_datetime()` into your datetime desired format.

Comment: I just tried your method, and it works up until the 60th minute - the 'min' column of the pandas dataframe just continues to go up. It doesn't reach 59 minutes and then switch over to hours - it just goes from 59 min 59 s, to 60 min 0 s..how would I account for this using your method?

Comment: It doesn´t switch to hours because the output format of your question was '%M:%S'.